# pushViewController not working properly

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, pushviewcontroller

I've got a SidebarMenueController which is my entry point after starting the app. 
Within there i've got a NavigationController embedded with a sidebar (slide out) menue. With sideBarDidSelectButtonAtIndex i catch which view, which should be loaded inside the NavigationController. When selecting an entry in the sidebar menue i want to push to another view.
Via printing (into the console) the selected menue entry, i can confirm that the selection is definitely working. But the pushViewController function is not loading the desired view.
I'm using no storyboard!
Any suggestions on how to fix this?

```
import UIKit

class SideBarMenueController: UIViewController, SideBarDelegate {

    var sideBar:SideBar = SideBar()

    lazy var menueButton: UIButton = {
        let button = UIButton()
        button.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 30, height: 30)
        button.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
        button.setImage(#imageLiteral(resourceName: "MenueIcon"), for: UIControlState.normal)
        button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(didSelectMenueButton), for: UIControlEvents.touchUpInside)
        return button
    }()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
        let sideBarMenue = UINavigationController(rootViewController:FirstViewController(collectionViewLayout: layout))
        self.addChildViewController(sideBarMenue)
        sideBarMenue.view.frame = self.view.bounds
        self.view.addSubview(sideBarMenue.view)

        UINavigationBar.appearance().barTintColor = UIColor(red: 70/255, green: 174/255, blue: 253/255, alpha: 1)

        let titleAttributes = [
            NSFontAttributeName: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 20, weight: UIFontWeightBold),
            NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.white
        ]
        UINavigationBar.appearance().titleTextAttributes = titleAttributes
        UINavigationBar.appearance().tintColor = UIColor.white

        let NavigationMenueButton = UIBarButtonItem(customView: menueButton)
        navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = NavigationMenueButton

        sideBar = SideBar(sourceView: self.view, menuItems: ["feed now", "feed times", "cats", "device status", "device setup", "about app"])
        sideBar.delegate = self
    }

    func didSelectMenueButton() {
        let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
        let controller = FeedTimesController(collectionViewLayout: layout)
        navigationController?.pushViewController(controller, animated: true)
    }

    func sideBarDidSelectButtonAtIndex(_ index: Int) {
        if index == 0{
            let controller = FirstViewController()
            navigationController?.pushViewController(controller, animated: true)
            print("touched index 0")
        } else if index == 1{
            let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
            let controller = SecondViewController(collectionViewLayout: layout)
            navigationController?.pushViewController(controller, animated: true)
            print("touched index 1")
        } else if index == 2{
            let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
            let controller = ThirdViewController(collectionViewLayout: layout)
            navigationController?.pushViewController(controller, animated: true)
            print("touched index 2")
        } else if index == 3{
            print("touched index 3")
        } else if index == 4{
            print("touched index 4")
        } else if index == 5{
            print("touched index 5")
        }

        sideBar.showSideBar(false)
    }
}
```

Comment: Would you mind posting a screenshot?

Comment: Of what specific part do you mean? The problem really only is the transition from the actual view to a new one via pushViewController.

Comment: This part "the pushViewController function is not loading the desired view." What is it loading?

Comment: it's doing nothing, the view still stays the same as it was before, i jumped through the code, the lines are executed and i get the index printed into the console, but nothing changes

Comment: Say index 2 is tapped. Does the print statement work?

Comment: Yes, that's correct.

Comment: Hmm have you tried `self.navigationController?.pushViewController(controller, animated: true)`?

Comment: Yes, i've already tried that one too. Same result

Comment: The navigationController could be nil. Try `self.presentViewController(controller, animated: true, completion: nil)`

Comment: I only can use presentedViewController or presentingViewController here.

Comment: Could you verify that self.navigationController is not nil?

Comment: How can i check that?

Comment: are you using storyboard ? if yes why don't you `instantiateviewcontrollerwithidentifier`, if you are not using storyboard, you need to make sure there is a navigationcontroller present

Comment: i'm not using storyboard. how can i make sure that the NavigationController is present? any hints on how to debug that one? Any other suggestions on how to solve this problem anyway?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are creating a NavigationController with:

```
let sideBarMenue = UINavigationController(rootViewController:FirstViewController(collectionViewLayout: layout))
```

Then you are adding that controller's view as a subview to self.view:

```
self.view.addSubview(sideBarMenue.view)
```

But then later, in didSelect, you are trying to access (implied) self.navigationController:

```
navigationController?.pushViewController(controller, animated: true)
```

Not sure, but it *looks* like you want to access the nav controller via:

```
sideBar.navigationController
```

Without seeing the code / library you're using for SideBar, this may or may not resolve your issue.

Comment: That's not working, getting a compiler error for that one.

Comment: Well, I think we need some more information. If you put a breakpoint in `sideBarDidSelectButtonAtIndex` and use the debug tools to see if `navigationController` is, in fact, valid... if it is (or isn't) find out where you are in the ViewController hierarchy relative to the UINavigationController you created.